# Why are distances to event horizons linear with mass when gravitational effects fall off as $1/r^2$?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, curvature, event-horizon

Black holes' gravitational effects fall off as $1/r^2$, but their event horizon grows linearly with increasing mass.  $R$ (event horizon) grows the same rate as $M$ (mass of black hole).  Okay lets put a ton of mass in there, so a lot of $R$, the effect of gravity will be vanishingly small at the event horizon since the effect diminishes as $1/r^2$. This is why certain supermassive black holes don't have tidal forces at their event horizons. So why is this an event horizon?  If event horizon means too much curvature of spacetime for light to escape... this seems confusing, what am I missing?

Comment: “*Okay lets put a ton of mass in there, so a lot of* $R,$ *the effect of gravity will be vanishingly small at the event horizon since the effect diminishes as* $1/^2$” - This is incorrect. Gravity diminishes (roughly) as a square of the (spacelike) radial *distance*. The spacelike radius of the horizon is always zero. So gravity diminishes as a square of the distance to the horizon and is always infinite at the horizon for a black hole of any mass. Your question question is based on a wrong premise.

Answer (score 4):

Forget black holes, just think about Newtonian physics.

The escape speed from some radius around a spherically symmetric mass is just where the sum of the kinetic and potential energy is zero. This yields
$$v_{\rm esc} = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}\ . $$
If we set this escape speed to some fixed threshold, then the radius at which this threshold occurs scales *linearly* with mass
$$ r = \frac{2GM}{v_{\rm esc}^2}\ . $$
So this isn't a surprise at all.

Secondly, tidal forces scale as $M/r^3$, so it is clear that the tidal forces at the threshold radius above will scale as $M^{-2}$. That is why the tidal forces at the event horizon of a supermassive black hole can be small.

In General Relativity, the event horizon is where everything, even light, is compelled to move towards smaller $r$. Thinking of it in terms of escape speed equalling the speed of light is not a valid thing to do, since, in Newtonian gravity, one can always escape at lower speeds by applying a force. This is not the case in GR.

Neither can you straightforwardly say that the gravitational effects fall off as $1/r^2$. It is more complex than that. The "weight" of an object near a black hole increases as $r^{-2}(1 - r_s/r)^{-1/2}$, where $r_s$ is the radial coordinate of the event horizon. This becomes infinite when $r=r_s$.

Tidal forces depend on the *gradient* of the gravitational force, not its absolute value. The Newtonian expression for tidal force turns out to be true for an object falling into a black hole too. Hence, there is no discontinuity or infinity at the event horizon and the tidal forces scale as $M^{-2}$ as in the Newtonian case.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn’t the escape speed there follow the sqrt of mass??

Comment: @PatrickWadsack-Stewart sure, but you asked why the event horizon depends linearly on mass.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say that a 2 kg dumbbell is hanging 100 m above event horizon. Let's say that when said dumbbell is dropped into the hole the mass of the hole increases by 100 grams. (This can happen theoretically.)

So it appears that the mass of the dumbbell, whose mass at infinity was 2 kg, was 100 grams when hanging near the horizon.

Now let us drop from infinity 100 tons of mass into the hole, while the 2 kg dumbbell is again hanging 100 above event horizon. Perhaps surprisingly this increases the mass of the hole by 100 tons and 90 grams. And then we again drop the 2 kg dumbbell into the hole. This time the mass of the hole increases by 10 grams.

Has the effect of horizon getting closer been explained well enough by this example?

The effects are: serious loss of mass of the object that the horizon gets closer to, slight increase of weight of said object, and serious freezing of the object. Freezing meaning freezing of motion.

All these changes of mass we know from some simple considerations considering conservation of mass.